# How to append webdeploy package to IIS site

Tags: powershell, iis, msdeploy, webdeploy

I would like to deploy a webapplication that is composed of multiple webdeploy packages in following sequence

1. webdeploy package containing website base (CMS files including
   web.config)
2. webdeploy package of specific module 1
3. webdeploy package of specific module 2
4. webdeploy package of application

Using PowerShell you can use the following commands to deploy a webdeploy package.

```bsh
Add-PSSnapin wdeploysnapin3.0
Restore-WDPackage -Package "Cms.Website.zip" -Parameters (Get-WDParameters -file .\Cms.Website.SetParameters.xml)
Restore-WDPackage -Package "Base.Modules.Login.zip" -Parameters (Get-WDParameters -file .\Base.Modules.Login.SetParameters.xml)
Restore-WDPackage -Package "Base.Modules.Search.zip" -Parameters (Get-WDParameters -file .\Base.Modules.Search.SetParameters.xml)
Restore-WDPackage -Package "CustomerABC.Website.zip" -Parameters (Get-WDParameters -file .\CustomerABC.Website.SetParameters.xml)
```

The problem is that the `Restore-WDPackage` causes the website (that is defined in the SetParameters file) to be cleared in every install.

I would like to clear the webroot during install of the first package, and I would like to be able to append files for the other 3 packages.

Does anyone know if this is possible using PowerShell commands?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see support for configuring rules with the `Restore-WDPackage` cmdlet.  If you can use the msdeploy.exe directly you can use the `-enableRule:DoNotDeleteRule` flag.

http://dotnetcatch.com/2016/02/01/webdeploymsdeploy-quick-tip-keep-existing-files-during-deployment/